# Drag a cell from 1 table view and drop it onto a cell in a 2nd table view to invoke segue

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to attain a visual interaction between two tables, inside one controller, by dragging and dropping a cell from one table onto another tables cell. When one dragged cell contacts another cell, a segue will be invoked to another controller.

A more detailed description: There are two standard UITableView's inside a UIViewController both that present data in cells utilizing a custom UITableViewCell class (nothing special in terms of what it does) - each cell presents an icon, name & a price. Both tables are placed side-to-side, rather than one on top of the other.

The point of all of this is to have the user tap a cell to create some kind of view object at the tapped location (something that represents the tapped cell) and drag it to the other table view. The dragged object can only be dropped on another cell. This DOESN'T add the dragged object to the other table; the object can only interact with a cell it was dragged & dropped over to invoke a segue to another controller (to do some stuff with the data of the dragged "cell" and the data of the contacted cell).

I've sat on this problem for a while, trying to figure it out. I've tried using touchesBegan & UIGestureRecognizers, but I can't even create some view object upon cell "touchdown" ('didSelectRowAtIndexPath' is useless since it gets called only when the finger is lifted...which null's the ability to drag). Please point me in the right direction or how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

About that touchDouwn event you mentioned, you can achieve that by doing this:
in `-(id)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

do

```
//init the cell "foo"
UIButton * bar = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,foo.frame.size.width, foo.frame.size.height);
[bar addTarget:self action:@selector(gotATouchDown:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

bar.tag = indexpath.row; //use this to know where touchDown happend

[foo addSubview:bar];
```

now the selector function

```
-(void)gotATouchDown:(UIButton*)sender{
    NSLog(@"I just touched row nr %ld ",sender.tag);
}
```

Not sure what to do next, once I figure it out I'll complete my answer.

Comment: Ey! Thanks a lot. That already gets me going in the right direction. I'm going to wait just a little bit more in case someone has the other part of the solution. If not, I'll "checkmark" this answer.

Comment: Have you tried using `UIControlEventTouchDragEnter` for the cells in second view?

Comment: I've applied it to my button but don't really get how to utilize it.

Comment: I have not tried it, but from the documentation, it should fire once you drag something on the button, so it should help with the "drop" part. (drag&Drop)

Comment: I finally got to a mac, and snap, there is no control event witch you can use for dropping, BUT there is [**THIS**](https://github.com/ice3-software/between-kit), let me know if it helps.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks for the link. I'm surprised I haven't found it when I was searching for pre-written code.